How to get element in CPythonScipt object?
I want to get the string in the pyscript object like in the image.
Can anyone help me?
I really appreciate your help!
enter image description here
You see in the image is the CPythonScriptObject.
I like to get the string, for exampple: 'pCT_AverageCT_22/03/2022'

What does patient.Cases[0].Examinations[0] output?

patient.Cases[0].Examinations[0] = <ScriptObject id=-2134716157, 'pCT_AverageCT_20200507'>

Not familiar with ScriptObject if it's standard object I can't find any documentation. Doe the elements have a .id property or .value you can access? It is an object and not a string yes?
